# AddThis How to change the images on Icons

Tags: css, add-in

So I have the following mark up

```
    <div class="socialMediaPlugin">
                <div class="socialMediaLinks">
                 <label>Share this page</label>
                    <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
                    <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a> 
                    <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
                 </div>
            </div>


            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4f8448d935e2a296"></script>
```

And css

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .socialMediaPlugin 
    {
        width: 738px;
        display: block;
        float: left;
    }

   .socialMediaLinks 
   {
        float: right;
        vertical-align:middle;
        border: 2px solid #DCDCDC;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
        background-color: white;
    }
    .socialMediaLinks a
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 3px;
        vertical-align:middle; 
    }
    .socialMediaPlugin label
    {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 15px;
    }
</style>
```

I am wondering if someone knows how I can change the icons on the social media buttons ? Especially for Pinterest I would like to do it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
<a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit">
  <img src="my_pintrest_icon.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Share" />
</a>
```

Change the img src to whatever you want

[Check this](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#.T4T2tjFlR5Y) for more info: